# Want to know how date() works

Tags: php

Hi I am trying a piece of code wherein I need the exact time.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date("y:d:m:H:i:s");

?>
```

It shows as the o/p `12:11:04:12:31:24` which is almost 2:30 hours behind the exact time. I am in Mumbai and i want the exact current time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which time zone is the server?

Comment: Try date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: replace Kolkata with Calcutta as said by @raymoonday

Comment: @RayMoonDay: That's an answer not a comment. It'll be a shame if someone read your comment, tested it in 10 seconds, posted it as an answer and get all the credit!

Comment: hey, replacing it with date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); does not help.. it still tells the same date and time. :(

Comment: Try to print the timezone after setting using date_default_timezone_get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RayMoonDay stated above:

> Try
>
> date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
>
> Check [php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)

I have not tested it - I am just putting it in answer form. If RayMoonDay posts this as an answer, I will edit this to remove that information.

However, I feel compelled to advise you against using `date()` and familiarize yourself with the `DateTime` class. `date()` may be fine for your application. but it has some known issues, especially with future dates.

DateTime: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format("y:d:m:H:i:s");
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It still tells the time 2 n half hour ago.

Comment: As I said I did not test the timezone issue, I was just relaying the info.